# three.js example with external resources not loading on jsfiddle.net

Tags: javascript, html, dom, three.js

I am trying to get this example project working:
github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-09/07-first-person-camera.html

I've tried mirroring the code on my pages.github.io account as well as making minor modifications for the purpose of running the code on jsfiddle.

IE. jsfiddle.net/bk4wm7sf/ (forked from: /5hcDs/)

The only change I made to the example was modification of the file locations(manually uploaded to jsfiddle as resources using rawgit.com for the CDN) and removal of the html code.

Ex:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../Metro01.JPG');
//texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
loader.load('../city.obj', '../city.mtl', load);
```

I also tried:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://rawgit.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/master/assets/textures/Metro01.JPG');
//texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
loader.load('https://rawgit.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/master/assets/models/city.obj', 'https://rawgit.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/master/assets/models/city.mtl', load);
```

Other attempts:
/zy448tn2/ & /jw20wtq5/ (this one has the rawgit urls)

I think the finished product is supposed to look like this:
http://www.smartjava.org/ltjs/chapter-09/07-first-person-camera.html

I saw some improvement by changing the jsfiddle setting "RequestAnimationFrame" from onLoad to "onDomready" but the city.obj file still isn't rendering.

I'm pretty new at javascript/three.js so my suspicion is this is a dumb question? Any help is appreciated.

**Update: Ok, so I was able to solve the 404 errors.**

I used feedback from my browser's javascript console to try ~14 different revs on jsfiddle. 
IE: /bk4wm7sf/1/ etc.

I eventually got frustrated when my console error messages started to change depending on the specific version of the file three.js I uploaded.

I wanted to eliminate jsfiddle and version incompatibilities as possible variables so I used "wget" to pull the individual .js files from the "known good" examples on smartjava and proceeded to upload them to my http://cantren.github.io page.
copyright acknowledgement here: cantren.github.io/blob/master/README.md

I think this has isolated the problem now to the "index.html" file but I'm running out of ideas...
github.com/cantren/cantren.github.io/blob/master/index.html

Now my javascript console is reading:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 63
2OBJMTLLoader.js:447 THREE.OBJMTLLoader: Unhandled line usemtl
```

Comment: If you open the console in your browser most of the external resources are 404, maybe they are behind a login screen?

Comment: Also, You will run into CORS problems loading images for textures. read [this](http://blog.2pha.com/using-threejs-jsfiddle)

Comment: 2pha, thank you for the tip on the CORS problems. That sort of "domain knowledge" would have taken me a long time to find independently. I'm currently debugging using cantren.github.io but once I have this example working I will be moving the code back to jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a verbatim Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V of the "known good" page source, then modified nothing except the file locations. This time it worked. Not sure why. Could run a "diff"/"diffchecker.com" but it works now so I'm happy. Thanks for the help!